# How to duplicate a widget in second window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to do the following: suppose I have a widget opening on a window (as QWidget). That widget includes some plot. I also have a second window (as QMainWindow) where I do stuff to that plot interactively: move it around and resize it. What I want is to create a third window that displays the **exact** same thing as the first window (the one with the plot) in real time. How could I go on doing this?

Why do I want this? The first window is going to be hidden and I want the third window so as to inspect that the correct thing is happening on the first one.

Comment: Your question seems interesting, but it's a bit confused. For instance, why is the first window hidden? Is it going to be shown at some time? If that's so, why? If I'm understanding correctly what you're asking, you're probably looking for some sort of "validation", but in that case having 2 "duplicate" widgets is not only unnecessary, but also wrong, logically and performance wise: you need the *visible* widget to be your main "control" widget, and only as soon as the "corrent things" have been completed, you'll generate the "actual" plot based on the modifications that have been applied.

Comment: Yeah, the "hidden" screen is somewhat weird, but it's supposed to be a micro meter sized 2d array of pixels and each pixels gets a voltage associated to it. But the array works as a second d screen. That's why its "hidden", as in "I don't see it". Does that help?

Comment: So the first window is going to go to this second screen and I will put it in full screen and control the plot within the window. I want the third window to duplicate the hidden one as a validation tool

Comment: Sorry, but, no, it doesn't help a lot. I suggest you to take your time and create a proper [mre] (it has to be *both* minimal *and* reproducible, and it might take a *lot* of time to do it, but, believe me, it's worth it) and do more efforts in clarifying what you're trying to achieve. I believe you might have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), as you probably need to consider the validation implementation in some other way that doesn't require "duplicating" a widget (or plot), since from your description it doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: Do you expect the third "validation" window to be fully interactive, or can it be a mainly visual display, like one of those magnifier tools? I suppose those must work by constantly updating screen grabs in a second window and copying the relative mouse cursor position. Would that be good enough for your purposes? It might allow a certain amount of interaction, if that was also needed.

Comment: The third window doesn't need to be interactive at all. That is, all I need the third window to do is to display the exact same thing as the first. Everytime something happens in the first window the third window should update itself to be the exact same. Ideally the third should just be a smaller version, preserving the aspect ratio. But that is a challenge for later, I guess

Comment: Well, that means all you need to do is set up a timer that periodically renders the widget to a pixmap (using [QWidget.grab](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab)) and then display it the third window. Of course, once you have the pixmap, you can easily [re-scale it](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled) as appropriate.

Comment: Hmm, that may actually do what I want! I'll give it a shot as soon as I can. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Cannot duplicate widgets. The closest thing is to create 2 widgets and in one of them you have to track the changes and apply them to the second (and vice versa). This task is not easy so I would recommend you only track some characteristics.